# Onclick срабатывает, когда это не нужно

Tags: javascript

Вопрос. Почему "Блин" срабатывает, когда я жму на один из этих эллементов

```
document.onclick = function () {
    if (window.i == 1) {
        var ctrl = true;
        document.getElementById('logo_text2').onmousedown = function () {
            ctrl = false
        }

        document.getElementById('phrase_text').onmousedown = function () {
            ctrl = false
        }

        document.getElementById('phrase_author').onmousedown = function () {
            ctrl = false
        }

        if (ctrl != false) {
            alert('Блин')
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну потому что Вы скорее всего не понимаете сами что вы тут написали. Как по вашему должен выполнятся этот код, что сначало, что потом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так у вас же ctrl объявлен через var в функции (следовательно - недоступен извне), а вы пытаетесь до него достучаться из сторонних функций. Плюс, onclick выполняется после onmousedown и не имеет с ним ничего общего.

Answer (score 0):

Убери строчку
    if (ctrl != false) {alert('Блин')
И все будет нормально.

Comment: И получим все равно "неожиданное" срабатывание document.onclick каждый раз

Comment: "Блин" то срабатывать не будет..

Answer (score 0):

короче надо так:

```
var ctrl = true;
function ctrlf(){
ctrl=false;
alert('Блин');
}
document.getElementById('logo_text2').onmousedown = ctrlf;
document.getElementById('phrase_text').onmousedown = ctrlf;
document.getElementById('phrase_author').onmousedown = ctrlf;
```

правильно я понял суть?